# Transform Avro file with Wrangler into JSON in cloud Datafusion

Tags: json, avro, google-cloud-data-fusion

I try to read an Avro file, make a basic transformation (remove records with name = Ben) using Wrangler and write the result as JSON file into google cloud storage.
The Avro file has the following schema:

{
"type": "record",
"name": "etlSchemaBody",
"fields": [
{
"type": "string",
"name": "name"
}
]
}

Transformation in wrangler is the following:
[transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBQU7.png)

The following is the output schema for JSON file:
[output schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKFT3.png)

When I run the pipeline it runs successfully and the JSON file is created in cloud storage. But the JSON output is empty.
When trying a preview run I get the following message:
[warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oklBX.png)

Why is the JSON output file in gcloud storage empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Wrangler to make transformations, the default values for the GCS source are `format: text` and `body: string` (data type); however, to properly work with an Avro file in the Wrangler you need to change that, you need to set the format to `blob` and the body data type to `bytes`, as follows:

[image: format]

[image: body data type]

After that, the preview for your pipeline should produce output records. You can see my working example next:

- [Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LskBt.png)
- [Transformations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBR27.png)
- [Input records preview for GCS sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAdPd.png) (final output)

**Edit:**

You need to set the `format: blob` and the output schema as `body: bytes` if you want to parse the file to Avro within the Wrangler, as described before, because it needs the content of the file in a binary format.

On the other hand if you only want to apply filters (within the Wrangler), you could do the following:

- Open the file using `format: avro`, [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkcxn.png).
- Set the output schema according to the fields that your Avro file has, in this case `name` with `string` data type, [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFhV0.png).
- Use only filters on the Wrangler (no parsing to Avro here), [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8CUx.png).

And this way you can also get the desired [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUZZK.png).

Comment: Great, it worked. Thanks. This is counterintuitive to select the format as "blob" instead of "avro" while reading .avro file

Comment: @AzamatTangirov That's because to parse the file as Avro, the Wrangler needs the content of the file in a binary format. If you read the file as Avro using the GCS source plugin, you'll have to handle the file differently and you won't even need to parse the file in the Wrangler and only use the filters. I've played a bit with the GCS source and the Wrangler and found a way to use the format Avro. I'll edit my answer and include that too.